# Filtering a nested relation in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, contentful

I have the following GraphQL query; "categories" is a one-to-many relationship, each containing a name and a slug. I want to get all Articles with category slug of "derp". Any thoughts?

```
{
allContentfulArticle(
  sort: { order: DESC, fields: [createdAt] }
) {
  edges {
    node {
      title
      slug
      datePublished
      createdAt
      categories {
        name
        slug
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contentful DevRel here.

I just prototyped your scenario and this query should do it.

```
query {
  categoryCollection(where: { slug_contains: "schnitzel" }) {
    items {
      linkedFrom {
        entryCollection {
          items {
            ...on Article {
              title 
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more info in the docs about links to [a specific entry](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/graphql/#links-to-a-specific-item).

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: not the same ... will it return the most recent articles (sorted by creation date desc)?

Comment: His suggestion does not do sorting, so I'm just doing that on the client end.

Comment: Thank you Stefan this worked perfectly for my use case!